# Finishing Child Activity from another child activity in android

Tags: android

I have a parent activity (as ACTIVITY GROUP) and some child activity of this parent activity (as ACTIVITY).
I am just calling child1 now i want to move from child1 to child2 and just want to finish() child1.
But when i am calling finish() it is also finishing the parent activity.

Plz send me a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

When you start child1 from parent, use `startActivityForResult`.  Then when you finish child1, `onActivityResult` will be called in parent.  From there, you can start child2.